# Mysqli statement execute error : Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mysqli, zend-db

While execution of an php script, i get an error description as,

Mysqli statement execute error : Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared.....

The function which performs the mysql execution ( insert / update statement) is an zend function _saveRow. Also it was observed that the data was been actually inserted in database and the function is still returning an execution error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *Any help will be appreciated.* I doubt you will get any help without the code that courses the error, your question attract downvotes

Comment: This is a duplicate, and [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22prepared+statement+needs+to+be+re-prepared%22).

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue: 'Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared'

This issue generally occurs at the time of calling procedure either by using any Computer Language(like Java) or Calling Procedures from the backend.

#### Solution: Increase the size of the cache by using (executing) below script.

Script: `set global table_definition_cache = 4000;`